# Sum until certain value

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum

i've tried some other topics for this but couldn't get answers that actually worked for me. 
I have a activities table with some values ( in mysql)

```
| id| user_id    |      elevation     | distance |
|---|------------|--------------------|----------|
| 1 | 1          | 220                | 5000     |
| 2 | 1          | 300                | 7000     |
| 3 | 2          | 520                | 2000     |
| 4 | 2          | 120                | 3500     |
```

I need to sum distance and elevation until distance sum up to certain value, per user_id.

Example, sum until 5000 is reached:

- User 1 - distance 5000 - elevation 220
- User 2 - distance 5500 - elevation 640

I found many solutions but none with group_by. How i do this in mysql?

---

Update : I used that query but now i'm with another problem. The join always use the insert order, and not a datetime field i want.

```
SELECT
t.*
FROM
(
    SELECT
        t.*,
        (
            @d := @d + DISTANCE


        ) AS running_distance
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                t.*,
                c.meta
            FROM
                inscricao i
            INNER JOIN categorias c ON
                i.categoria_id = c.id
            LEFT JOIN(
                    select
                        t.data_inicio,t.usuario_id,t.aplicativo,t.data_fim,t.distance,t.tempo_decorrido,t.ritmo_cardiaco,t.velocidade_media,t.type,t.ganho_de_altimetria
                    from
                        corridas t
                    order by
                        data_inicio asc
                ) t ON
                t.usuario_id = i.usuario_id
                AND t.data_inicio >= i.inicio
                AND t.data_fim <= i.fim
            WHERE
                i.desafio_id = 29
                AND(
                    i.usuario_id = 5354
                )
            ORDER BY
                data_inicio asc
                -- usuario_id
        ) t 
     join (
            SELECT
                @u :=- 1,
                @d := 0
        ) params
        ORDER BY
                data_inicio asc
) t 
WHERE
(
    running_distance >= meta * 1000
    AND running_distance - DISTANCE < meta * 1000
)
OR(
    running_distance <= meta * 1000
)
order by
data_inicio desc
```

So if a older activity is inserted after, the sum gets wrong. Someone knows how to handle it?

Comment: Why do you have to use group_by?

Comment: @mypetlion How else would you get one total per user ID?

Comment: You said you found many solutions but none with group_by. I guess I didn't know what you meant. You mean you've found solutions that will do what you want for the table in general, but not for each user_id?

Comment: I have to rank my users by total distance, and in case of a tie, rank by elevation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use variables to get the cumulative sum . . . then some simple filtering logic:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (@d := if(@u = user_id, @d + distance,
                       if(@u := user_id, distance, distance)
                      )
             ) as running_distance  -- pun intended ??
      from (select t.*
            from t
            order by user_id, id
           ) t cross join
           (select @u := -1, @d := 0) params
     ) t
where running_distance >= 5000 and
      running_distance - distance < 5000;
```

Notes:

- The more recent versions of MySQL are finicky about variable assignment and `order by`.  The innermost subquery is not needed in earlier versions of MySQL.
- MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in a `select`.  Hence, all variable assignments are in a single expression.
- If distance can be negative, then a user may have more than one row in the result set.
- This is not an aggregation query.